# Modal Windows on iOS

Tags: livecode

I'm developing a game in Livecode that, when the player has finished, will ask them if they want to play again.

When running on the PC, I can make this happen by using `modal stack stackname`. The stack appears as I designed it in the editor.

When this runs on the iOS emulator ( and I presume on an iOS device ) , the modal stack occupies the whole screen and is pretty unappealing.

What's the best practise when faced with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Dave.  You could just create a card specifically for that purpose.  It will look a lot nicer :)

```
go card "gameOver"
```

and the card can contain the choices to start a new game. view scores or whatever other options you have.

Comment: When I do that, the new Card occupies the same space as the card where the game is played, so it effectively does the same thing as the modal stack when run on iOS. Am I missing your point?

Comment: No - sorry, Dave - I think I missed the point  :D  I thought you were showing a dialog box rather than a stack...

Comment: Dave, on mobile devices it is supposed to be like that. Please, re-consider your design. Only for simple, brief messages, one uses modal dialogs and LiveCode does those just fine, using the answer command.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile apps are limited to one window at a time, except for the special ask and answer dialogs. You could fake a modal with a group though, and show or hide it as needed.

Comment: The problem with using groups is that you also need to disable all controls that aren't covered by objects in the group. You may solve this with a graphic or image of the same size as the card, but Splas21's solution, which uses a dedicated card for the dialog, looks better and is easier to implement.

Comment: Yes, either way would work. If a separate card is used, a snapshot of the original card should be placed behind the "modal" objects in order to make it look like a real dialog. Since that's about the same thing as placing an image behind the group, it's a tossup. Either method would look identical.

Comment: If it is for entering data, you really don't need to fake a background.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and cleanest solution is the create a stack with multiple cards as Splash21 pointed out:

1) Open your stack
2) Create a new card (object menu > new card)
3) Name your card (object menu > card inspector)

```
go card "gameOver"
```

If it makes sense for your app to be broken up into multiple stacks you can use the following syntax to load the new stack in the current window:

```
go stack "newStackName" in window stack "currentStackName"
```